# How to make sequence diagrams independent from each other in Papyrus?

Tags: eclipse, uml, papyrus

I'm using Eclipse Neon (4.6) with Papyrus (2.0) and created two sequence diagrams. I'm struggling to set different properties in them. For instance if I change the name in diagram 1 the name will also be changed in diagram 2. I cannot find a way to set a different name! I also have gates on both diagrams although I only drew them for one diagram and I cannot get rid of them anymore. They can only be removed or added in both diagrams!

Comment: I don't know Papyrus, but this looks like you are not using instances. The elements in SD need to be instances of classes, rather than the classes themselves.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few restarts of Eclipse I created a new sequence diagram and noticed that problems don't occure anymore.